# Getting error argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, openpyxl

I tried using

```
i=2 
int(Rawsheet.cell(i, column=4).value)
```

it works but if I increment value `i+=1` it gives below error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? What do/don't you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the `Rawsheet.cell(i, column=4).value` it returns None when `i` is more than 2.

Comment: Sheet has values at if I use row=2,column=4 it works.... but when I use below it gives error.......i=1

for row in range(Rawsheet.max_row):

      i+=1

      for col in range(Rawsheet.max_column):

            if int(Rawsheet.cell(i, column=4).value) > Testdetailsheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value:

              Top5sheet.cell(row+1, col+1).value=Rawsheet.cell(row+1, col+1).value